# Getting 2 result from one query with elequent laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to get 2 result from a filter query in Laravel version 6. I want to get product table information that user can change item exist in page by a select box with name of `pageitemcount` and can search by a field with name of `select`. when user select `pageitemcount` and also search for an name, submit a form and below query is run . When user search anything, available filter of category must be limited to available categories. I want to show distinct product category in additional to product list.

```
public function productIndex(Request $request)
{
   $take = 10;

   $query = Product::query();

   if ($request->has('pageitem')){
       $take = $request->input("pageitem");
   }

   // Search
   if ($request->has('search')){
       $query = $query->where('name', $request->input("search"));
   }

   $availableCategoriesQuery= $query;

   // Get product unique product category to show them to user 
   // that exist in prodcut list that show to user
   $availableCategories = $availableCategoriesQuery->select("category_id")->distinct()->get();

   // Get product list by pagination
   $productList = $query->paginate($take);

   return view('admin.manage_product', ['productList' => $productList, 'availableCategories' => $availableCategories]);
}
```

but when `$availableCategories` is executed, affected `$query` variable, and i cant get right result from next line, i get result of `$availableCategories` in `$productList` variable. i do'nt want to repeat my code again, how can i deal with?

the result of $availableCategories is completely true, but result of `productList` is `$availableCategories` that is paginated.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you are asking. Try posting some sample $request information and what kind of response you are looking for. If you are looking to get two completely different queries, it's probably better to run them separately.

Comment: I try to clear that, i want to send 2 separate result of this query to user

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I see the problem. You are trying to reuse the `$query` variable. You probably want something like this:

I assume that `product_categories` is the table for your product categories. You can also use the model if you want.

Also, Since the DB has no intrinsic order, you should specify an `OrderBy()` as well.

```
$take = $request->input("pageitem", 10);
$productList = Product::paginate($take)->get();
$availableCategories = DB::table('product_categories')->distinct()->get("category_id");
```

Comment: In this way that you say, its true, but may be some product category does not exist in the product list when user search for specific name.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. The idea of pagination is to show only a few items at a time. So, by definition, there will be some items missing.

Comment: i just want to have filters,when user search anything, available filter of category must be limited to available categories.

Comment: Then, perhaps you want something like `$productList = Product::where('product_category', $request->input('xxx'))->paginate($take)->get();`

Comment: but above query cant get me availableproduct category of product result.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just can't figure out what you are asking. Please try to post some example data with what you expect to see with different inputs. Maybe then we can help more. Show the definitions of your tables and models.